# Can I use Python scripting to fill out fields on a program locally in my computer?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to use AgentRansack, a search program, to find all files in a directory containing certain text. I could write a script to open each file in the directory and search the text. However, just entering the directory, the term to search and hitting the start button in agent ransack should do the job.

Is it possible to use scripts in order to fill out forms in programs locally (like AgentRansack)?

![AgentRansack program template]https://img.utdstc.com/screen/windows/thumb/agent-ransack.jpg!

Comment: You should look at using a terminal command like grep for unix/mac. Scripting a ui is possible but very cumbersome.

Comment: You might be better off using shell/terminal commands to do the job, as having to deal with GUI elements programmatically can turn into a major source of complexity and issues. For example, in GNU/Linux, you can use the `find` command along with some options. If you're in Windows, you should be able to find something analogous to this. Even if you want to write your script, it'll still be easier to invoke another script from yours than sending GUI keys.

Answer (score 0):

I have had luck before with [WinGUIAuto](https://pywinauto.github.io/docs/).  It uses `Sendkeys` method to literally send keys to other Windows application.  However, a simple focus grab between windows applications could mess with the whole process, so not a production grade stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python to call windows' `findstr` :

```
findstr /spin /c:"string" [files]
```

The parameters have the following meanings:

- `s` = recursive
- `p` = skip non-printable characters
- `i` = case insensitive
- `n` = print line numbers

And the string to search for is the bit you put in quotes after `/c:`